# Error with Numpy library SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, error-handling, syntax

I'm using numpy library to create an array. I ran the following code:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.random((2,3)) = array([[0.60793904,0.02881965,0.73022145], 0.34183628,0.63274067,0.07945224]])

np.zeros((2,3)) = array([[0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.]])
np.zeros((2,3)) = array([[1.,1.,1.],[1.,1.,1.]])
np.zeros((2,3)) = array([[1.,1.,1.],[1.,1.,1.]])
np.zeros(3) = array([[1.,0.,0.],[0.,1.,0.],[0.,0.,1.]])
```

And it gave an error message saying

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16828/3377000396.py", line 2
    np.random.random((2,3)) = array([[0.60793904,0.02881965,0.73022145],[0.34183628,0.63274067,0.07945224]])
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

Please how do I fix this error?

Comment: What is that line supposed to be doing?

Comment: Why are you assigning function calls to  array?s it doesn't make sense

Comment: A syntax error means you are doing something wrong a the Python code level.  This isn't a `numpy` issue.  This is basic Python.

Answer (score 0):

you can't assign a function return value to something:

Example:

```
def func(i,j):
    return random.choice(i,j)
func(1,2) = np.array([0,1,0])
```

in this case you are assigning an integer value to a numpy array, you , so *you cannot do that* b/c the compiler wouldn't understand

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - "how do I fix this error?"